# Importing react native native module JS not working but importing native module from NativeModules does?

Tags: react-native, react-native-native-module

When importing a react-native native module. There is an issue when importing the js from the project for example

```js
import RNModule from 'react-native-module';
```

However importing RNModule using native modules works:

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { RNModule } = NativeModules;
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

I've already tried clearing all the recommended caches as well as rebuilding.

I've tried importing from both the project name `react-native-module` and the file name `rn-module`

Example project:
https://github.com/814k31/TestReactNativeNativeModule

(Build and run instructions in README)

This is the import that doesn't work
https://github.com/814k31/TestReactNativeNativeModule/blob/master/RNApp/App.js#L13

But this one does work.

When the button is clicked it will trigger a native `Android` function

https://github.com/814k31/TestReactNativeNativeModule/blob/master/rn-module/android/src/main/java/com/reactlibrary/RNModuleModule.java#L18

and should make `Hello World From RNModule` appear on the screen.

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: @HeisenBrg 

if I attempt to import the javascript file using this line
`import RNModule from 'react-native-module';`

I get `react-native-module` not found in haste module map

However the package exists in NativeModules

Comment: There is no module called `react-native-module`, so it doesn't work.

Comment: @10101010 so what would the module be called?

Because I am importing a module called `react-native-module`

https://github.com/814k31/TestReactNativeNativeModule/blob/master/RNApp/package.json#L13

Which is declared https://github.com/814k31/TestReactNativeNativeModule/blob/master/rn-module/package.json#L3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metro bundler doesn't support symlinks...